# Can we have Fine-Grained Access Control (table level) in Amazon Aurora?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am looking in Amazon Aurora to have Fine-Grained Access Control using IAM policies. eg - If user doesn't have permission to access few attributes of Aurora table , should not be able to access/view those.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't control that with IAM policies**. You have to use regular mysql/postresql level permissions for your users.